# Unable to edit other posts

Tags: discussion, review

I have been reviewing other posts for some time. But after a certain number of edits I am no longer able to edit any further post.

Why is it so?

Comment: Here is a few possible reasons http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide This "At most 5 pending suggested edits per editor (20 on beta sites)" seems likely if you edit a lot of posts.